# Is this called a nest?

Tags: word-usage, image-identification

A nest normally looks like this

[image: A nest of robins in a hawthorn tree. Photo by Cheri Kaufman.]
<sub>(Photo by Cheri Kaufman)</sub>

This nest made of straws normally by birds.

What if a human made a hole in a tree like this for birds to live in

[image: An illustration of a hole in the trunk of a tree with bird eggs and a hatching bird]

**Is this also a nest?**

Comment: I think I voted to close for the wrong reason. I vtc'd as many dictionaries should show that animals can build many kinds of nests in many places, or that a nest can be human-made as long as an animal uses it for nesting. But I think I ought to vtc as lacking details or clarity, as Paul has the important answer: If the birds never used it, I would describe such a hole with a phrase that included "nesting": nesting cavity, nesting place, etc. (In US people often put out "nesting boxes" for bluebirds.) This question doesn't make it clear whether it's asking about the hole or the actual nest.

Comment: In your native language would you use the same word for both? This isn't really a question about English, is it?

Comment: The birds would probably _make a nest in the hole in the tree_. Some seabirds lay their eggs on the bare rock of  ledges in cliffs, but most species gather some kind of plant material to make a bed for the young ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re asking about the man-made cavity, that could be called a *nesting place* but is not itself the nest. The twig-structure within it is the nest, regardless whether made by bird or human.

As [this source](https://avianreport.com/why-do-cavity-nesting-birds-fight-for-birdhouses/) explains, “A cavity-nesting bird **builds nests**, lays eggs, and raises young **inside a cavity**” (emphasis added).

To be sure, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_nest) explains, some species of birds don’t build any structures at all. Their nests can be mere depressions in the ground, or indeed otherwise empty cavities in trees. But in the case of your illustration, which may be thought of as our stereotypical concept, the nest is the “improvements” within the cavity rather than the cavity itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Types of bird nests](https://goldengatebirdalliance.org/conservation/make-the-city-safe-for-wildlife/tree-care-and-bird-safety/types-of-bird-nests/)

The one in the question is a cavity nest. Below is proof of that from a specialized site.
(Easy to google, by the way)

> **Scrape nests** are simple depressions in the ground (sometimes with a few stones or leaves added), or in the leaf litter. Such nests are
> used by shorebirds, gulls, terns, nighthawks, vultures, and other
> species.
>
> **Burrow nests** are very effective at protecting eggs and young from predators and maintaining an appropriate microclimate for eggs and
> young. Some birds, like Bank Swallows and Belted Kingfishers, usually
> construct their own burrows, while others, such as Burrowing Owls, may
> use the burrows constructed by other species.
>
> **Cavity nests** are used by numerous passerines, woodpeckers, owls, parrots, and some waterfowl. Woodpeckers construct their own cavity
> nests and are referred to as primary cavity nesters. Species that use
> natural cavities or cavities constructed by primary cavity nesters are
> called secondary cavity nesters.
>
> **Platform nests** are relatively flat nests that may be located on the ground, in a tree, or on the tops of rooted vegetation or debris
> in shallow water.
>
> Cupped nests are, of course, cup shaped. Such nests may be constructed
> of various materials and in a variety of locations. Noted
> ornithologist Olin Sewall Pettingill subcategorized cup nests as
> follows:
>
> **Supported cupped nests**: are those located in the crotches and branches of trees and shrubs, supported mainly from below. Many
> passerines and hummingbirds build such nests.
>
> **Suspended cupped nests**: are not supported from below but from the rims, sides or both.
>
> **Pensile**: nests are suspended from the rims and sides; rather stiff (e.g. those of kinglets and vireos).
>
> **Adherent** nests: cupped nests whose sides are attached by an adhesive substance (e.g. mud or saliva) to a vertical surface, like
> those of swifts and some swallows.
>
> **Ground nests**: include cupped nests on the ground; sides are sometimes extended upward and arched over the top making a domed
> structure. Several passerines, particularly those that occupy open
> habitats like grasslands, build ground nests.  A local example is the
> White-crowned Sparrow.

Answer (score 0):

They are both nests. A nest is any space that a living creature creates or uses to live in or raise young. Many birds create them out of twigs or other materials, and some use holes in trees or the ground as nests.

> a : a bed or receptacle prepared by an animal and especially a bird
> for its eggs and young
>
> b : a place or specially modified structure
> serving as an abode of animals and especially of their immature stages
> an ants' nest

[Nest (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nest)

[image]